# Which character will perform the most damage, assuming the same level/gear?

Tags: borderlands-2

Okay so I have Zer0 at level 42 /w bee shield and specced for pistols (rapid fire over pure damage) but I feel that Salvador could hit harder than I could burst, now I don't use the best pistol in the world, ~1200 damage and I'm specced cunning, the bee shield is a lvl 35 item.

So am I incorrect that Salvador could hit harder, outside of Gunzerker? I think Salvador could hit a lot harder even with zer0 using deception at 0.01 fire time.

So in your experiences what sort of damages has your characters been hitting? I would just love to see if someone like Salvador could hit harder than zer0 at same level and gear etc.

Comment: Could depend on the type of damage you want. Burst damage on one target, or global one (including splash), for example.

Comment: I would prefer splash but i would also like to know about burst damage :)

Comment: @XDroidie626 - I've edited your title to be more relevant. I've also removed your secondary question, you should ask that as it's own question :)

Answer (score 2):

Zer0 is sniper/melee. Deception only effects the first hit, so it had better be a critical. Ideally with a gun that has a bonus to crits (Sniper rifle's +200 critical hit, with deception's +200 gun and +250 crit.) Zero is not Mordecai and has no specs specific to pistols. The Mecromancer has The Better Half skill (7/5, +84% fire rate when the **magazine is half empty**.) Repeaters almost empty themselves. In Borderlands1, Mordecai has a pistol fire rate increase. Zero's only fire rate increase is Fearless (5/5, +25% fire rate when **shield is depleted**, boo!)

Comment: But how does all this damage stack up against salvadors damage? With or without action skill

Answer (score 0):

It depends more on the gear than the character using it. Yes, there are numerous skills that affect fire rate, crits, etc (which can be boosted by COMs), but the weapon itself is more important.

But to give you an answer, a Sniper Zero with a big pile of Critical Ascension stacks and the right Sniper Rifle can out-damage just about any other character in the game. A Salvador could compete (and kill a raid boss quicker), but only if Money Shot procs.